# p5.js Flood Fill (bucket tool) works slowly and wierd

Tags: javascript, p5.js, flood-fill

So I wrote a flood fill function that works like a paint-app bucket tool: you click inside a closed shape and it'll fill with a color.

I have two problems with it:

1. performance - let's say my canvas is 600*600 (370,000 pixels) and I draw a big circle in it that for example has about 100K pixels in it, it can take about 40(!!!) seconds to fill this circle! thats insane!
   A sqaure of exactly 10,000 pixels takes 0.4-0.5 seconds on average, but (I guess) since the sizes of the arrays used the program are growing so much, a sqaure 10 times the size takes about 100 times the length to fill.
2. there's something wierd about the filling. I'm not really sure how it happens but it's always leaving a few un-filled pixels. Not much at all, but it's really wierd.

My flood fill function uses 4 helper-functions: get and set pixel color, checking if it's a color to fill, and checking if that's a pixel that has been checked before.
Here are all the functions:

```
getPixelColor = (x, y) => {
  let pixelColor = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < pixDens; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pixDens; ++j) {
      index = 4 * ((y * pixDens + j) * width * pixDens + (x * pixDens + i));
      pixelColor[0] = pixels[index];
      pixelColor[1] = pixels[index + 1];
      pixelColor[2] = pixels[index + 2];
      pixelColor[3] = pixels[index + 3];
    }
  }
  return pixelColor;
};

setPixelColor = (x, y, currentColor) => { //Remember to loadPixels() before using this function, and to updatePixels() after.
  for (let i = 0; i < pixDens; ++i) {
    for (let j = 0; j < pixDens; ++j) {
      index = 4 * ((y * pixDens + j) * width * pixDens + (x * pixDens + i));
      pixels[index] = currentColor[0];
      pixels[index + 1] = currentColor[1];
      pixels[index + 2] = currentColor[2];
      pixels[index + 3] = currentColor[3];
    }
  }
}

isDuplicate = (posHistory, vector) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < posHistory.length; ++i) {
    if (posHistory[i].x === vector.x && posHistory[i].y === vector.y) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

compareColors = (firstColor, secondColor) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < firstColor.length; ++i) {
    if (firstColor[i] !== secondColor[i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}

floodFill = () => {
  loadPixels();
  let x = floor(mouseX);
  let y = floor(mouseY);
  let startingColor = getPixelColor(x, y);
  if (compareColors(startingColor, currentColor)) {
    return false;
  }
  let pos = [];
  pos.push(createVector(x, y));
  let posHistory = [];
  posHistory.push(createVector(x, y));
  while (pos.length > 0) {
    x = pos[0].x;
    y = pos[0].y;
    pos.shift();
    if (x <= width && x >= 0 && y <= height && y >= 0) {
      setPixelColor(x, y, currentColor);
      let xMinus = createVector(x - 1, y);
      if (!isDuplicate(posHistory, xMinus) && compareColors(getPixelColor(xMinus.x, xMinus.y), startingColor)) {
        pos.push(xMinus);
        posHistory.push(xMinus);
      }
      let xPlus = createVector(x + 1, y);
      if (!isDuplicate(posHistory, xPlus) && compareColors(getPixelColor(xPlus.x, xPlus.y), startingColor)) {
        pos.push(xPlus);
        posHistory.push(xPlus);
      }
      let yMinus = createVector(x, y - 1);
      if (!isDuplicate(posHistory, yMinus) && compareColors(getPixelColor(yMinus.x, yMinus.y), startingColor)) {
        pos.push(yMinus);
        posHistory.push(yMinus);
      }
      let yPlus = createVector(x, y + 1);
      if (!isDuplicate(posHistory, yPlus) && compareColors(getPixelColor(yPlus.x, yPlus.y), startingColor)) {
        pos.push(yPlus);
        posHistory.push(yPlus);
      }
    }
  }
  updatePixels();
}
```

I would really apprciate it if someone could help me solve the problems with the functions.
Thank you very much!!

EDIT: So I updated my flood fill function itself and removed an array of colors that I never used. this array was pretty large and a few push() and a shift() methods called on it on pretty much every run.
UNFORTUNATLY, the execution time is 99.9% the same for small shapes (for example, a fill of 10,000 takes the same 0.5 seconds, but large fills, like 100,000 pixels now takes about 30 seconds and not 40, so that's a step in the right direction.
I guess that RAM usage is down as well since it was a pretty large array but I didn't measured it.
The wierd problem where it leaves un-filled pixels behind is still here as well.

Answer (score 0):

A little suggestion:

You don't actually have to use the `posHistory` array to determine whether to set color. If the current pixel has the same color as `startingColor` then set color, otherwise don't set. This would have the same effect.

The `posHistory` array would grow larger and larger during execution. As a result, a lot of work has to be done just to determine whether to fill a single pixel. I think this might be the reason behind your code running slowly.

As for the "weird thing":

This also happened to me before. I think that's because the unfilled pixels do not have the same color as `startingColor`. Say you draw a black shape on a white background, you would expect to see some gray pixels (close to white) between the black and white parts somewhere. These pixels play the role of smoothing the shape.